# How can I set multiple conditions on the same *ngIf within a tag?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if

I have a `form` with multiple fields in angular material. In a field I need to establish the condition that if the user is "admin" it occupies 2 columns of the table, if not, it occupies 3 columns.

This is my current code:

```
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">
     <div fxFlex>
          <date fxFlex title="Fecha inicio" [monthInput]="true" formControlName="date"></date>
     </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

This is the code that I am testing but I can't get it to work:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngIf="is_admin; then [colspan]="2"; else [colspan]="3"">
     <div fxFlex>
          <date fxFlex title="Fecha inicio" [monthInput]="true" formControlName="date"></date>
     </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

How can I set the condition inside the label to get it to fit the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[colspan]="is_admin ? 2 : 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `*ngIf` for this as `*ngIf` controls whether an element is visible or not.

You can use an expression inside the property binding:

```
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="is_admin ? 2 : 3">
     <div fxFlex>
          <date fxFlex title="Fecha inicio" [monthInput]="true" formControlName="date"></date>
     </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

You can find more information about Angular's Binding Syntax [here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can work around with two approaches:

Using property binding

```
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="is_admin ? 2 : 3">
     <div fxFlex>
          <date fxFlex title="Fecha inicio" [monthInput]="true" formControlName="date"></date>
     </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

or, If you are still interested in `*ngIf`

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngIf="is_admin else not_admin" [colspan]="2">
     <div fxFlex>
          <date fxFlex title="Fecha inicio" [monthInput]="true" formControlName="date"></date>
     </div>
</mat-grid-tile>

<ng-template #not_admin>
 <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">
     <div fxFlex>
          <date fxFlex title="Fecha inicio" [monthInput]="true" formControlName="date"></date>
     </div>
 </mat-grid-tile>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[colSpan]="is_admin ? 2 : 3"
```

or

```
colSpan="{{ is_admin ? 2 : 3 }}"
```

Either one works just fine. But the top method is more preferred as its easy to read too!

Answer (score -3):

```
*ngIf="is_admin; then [colspan]="2"; else [colspan]="3""
                                   ^
                                   |
```

simply remove this semicolon?